# Query by several values (Logical "or") on Cloud Firebase's Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing an app that returns posts by users I follow, so I would like to query a collection and return documents matching either one of the users I follow (logical OR).

Is there a way to return all posts written by ANY of the users in that array without having to query them individually? I am thinking something like:

```
postsRef
    .whereField("user", isEqualTo: "user1 || user2 || user3")
```

This would be the equivalent on MongoDB using **$in**:

```
postsRef.find( { user: { $in: [ user1, user2 ] } } )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I contacted Firebase support about this and this was their answer:

> Regarding your question, technically it's not yet supported in Cloud Firestore.
>
> For the meantime, you may find this [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) helpful in formulating a workaround.

I found this other link to be more useful, which basically tells people to use an indexing service like "Algolia"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search